# How to seet how many DIV I want on a line

Tags: php, html, css

I have an array containing strings in PHP.

I would like to display my strings in tables.

I would like to display them on "X" lines and 3 columns, so X lines of 3 divs elements containing strings.

I actually put it on a single DIV then I use a foreach, all my DIV's are on the same line.

Is there a simple way to force a return each 3 divs ?

Here is what I do actually :

```
<TABLE>     
<?php
foreach ($listeProfilProjets as $profilProjets)
{   
?><DIV>
    <TD>                    
        <TABLE id="drop-<?=$profilProjets['id'] ?>">
            <TR><TH><?=$profilProjets['prf_lib'] ?></TH><TH>Action</TH><TR>
            <TR><TD border=1> <input  class="destination" id="<?=$profilProjets['id'] ?>" ondragover="onDragOver(event)" ondrop="onDrop(event)" type="text" style="border: 1px solid;" value="Zone de dépôt"> </TD>
                <TR>
                    <?php foreach ($listeConsultantProfilProjets as $consutltantProfilProjets)
                    {
                        if ($consutltantProfilProjets['profil_projet_id'] == $profilProjets['id'])
                        {
                            echo '<TR><TD>' . $consutltantProfilProjets['con_nom'] . ' ' . $consutltantProfilProjets['con_prenom'] . '</TD>';
                    ?>   
                    <td>
                        <a class='delbtn' data-type='ConsultantProfilProjet' data-id=<?php echo $consutltantProfilProjets['id']; ?> href='javascript:void(0)'>Supprimer</a>
                    </td>
                </TR>
                <?php
                }
    } ?>

        </TABLE>
    </TD>
 </DIV>
 <?php
}
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: It look like you arent ending the tr for the head properly, I don't know much php though so it could be something else

Comment: There are several TRs that you're not closing properly. If you view the page source in the browser, you'll be able to see exactly which are opened and which are closed. For instance, the first Action has an opening TR instead of a closing TR. (5 `<TR>` tags, only 1 `</TR>` tag in the code shown here)

Comment: Also, you have a TD inside of a DIV, which really isn't proper HTML. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Comment: Yeah, the code is ugly and not from me. But how to "set" i want only 3 divs on the same line ?

Comment: You don't actually have to close `<tr>` or `<td>` tags. They have optional end tags (not saying that is a good idea, just that it's technically okay).

Comment: Yes, but how to force only 3 elements on a line, instead all on the same line ?

Comment: I haven't got the time to write a full answer (if nobody does, be sure to self-answer your question to help others!) but if you increment a variable every loop (`$i = 0; foreach(...) {  /* existing code */ $i++; }`) then you can use the *modulo operator*, `%`, to check if it's every third iteration or not: `if ($i % 3 === 0) { /* print a <tr> */ }`. You'll also need to remove those outer `<div>` elements for sure.

Comment: Please clarify your problem. Do you want to solve this using PHP, or using CSS?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function createDiv(){

const div = document.createElement("div");
div.classList.add("element");
div.innerHTML = "loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum";
document.getElementById("struct").appendChild(div);
}

function pageScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0,25);
}
```

```css
.element{
border : 1px solid black;
width : 120px;
height : 60px;
padding : 5px;
}

#struct{
display: inline-grid;
grid-template-columns: 150px 150px 150px;
grid-template-rows: repeat(999,90px);
}

#btn{
font: 1.3em "Arial", sans-serif;
width : 140px;
height : 50px;
position : fixed;
bottom : 15px;
right : 15px;
background-color : white;
border : 1x solid black;
padding : 5px;
}

#btn:hover{
background-color : black;
color : white;
cursor : pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="createDiv();pageScroll()" value="Add new div" id="btn">

<div id = "struct">
  <div class = "element">
  loreum ipsum
  loreum ipsum 
  loreum ipsum
  </div>

  <div class = "element">
  loreum ipsum
  loreum ipsum 
  loreum ipsum
  </div>

  <div class = "element">
  loreum ipsum
  loreum ipsum 
  loreum ipsum
  </div>
  
</div>
```

I see you used the CSS tag in your question so what you can do is :

Styling your container where you generate your divs and apply the following property :

`display : inline-grid`

Then use `grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%` to set the number of column to 3. Here 33% is a totally arbitrary value, this is the width of the column.

If you want 4 divs per line you set `grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%`,

If you want 5 divs per line you set `grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%`, etc...

But I suggest you use px instead of %.

Check [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) for more informations.
Best regards,

Hugo.